# Simple Spring Web Project Not Working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've been trying to learn how to develop a Spring Web application and can't seem to get it working. Using the Spring Tool Suite, I created a new Spring Project using the `Simple Spring Web Maven` template, which basically is comprised of four files:

`index.jsp`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <c:url value="/showMessage.html" var="messageUrl" />
        <a href="${messageUrl}">Click to enter</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

`/WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>spring-web-test</display-name>

   <!--
        - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
        - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!--
        - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

`/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Uncomment and your base-package here:
         <context:component-scan
            base-package="org.springframework.samples.web"/>  -->


    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'showMessage' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/showMessage.jsp' -->
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

`/WEB-INF/view/showMessage.jsp`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <h2>${message}</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

This all seemed simple and basic enough, so I built it using Maven and packaged it into a WAR file. I then deployed it to a local TomEE 7 server, went to http://localhost:8080/spring-web-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, and got to the very simple index.jsp page:

[image: Index Page]

However, when clicking the link, which sends me to http://localhost:8080/spring-web-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/showMessage.html, I get a 404 error from Tomcat:

[image: Tomcat 404 Error]

I suspected it was because of the .html ending - based off what I understand of the dispatcher and view resolver, it would be looking for `/WEB-INF/view/showMessage.html.jsp`. However, trying to access http://localhost:8080/spring-web-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/showMessage returns the same error. Looking at the Tomcat logs, I see

```
Nov 11, 2015 9:46:53 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring-web-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/showMessage.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
Nov 11, 2015 9:46:55 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring-web-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/showMessage] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

What am I doing wrong? The whole thing seems pretty simple, and I haven't even modified anything from the template Spring Tool Suite provides, so I'd have assumed it would work right out of the box. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of resources online on developing Spring web applications for use in servlet containers, and of the ones I've found, nothing seemed to suggest I'm doing anything wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your index.jsp to something like this

```
 <c:url value="/showMessage" var="messageUrl" />
```

You don't need file extensions, because you've set them up in your mvc-config.xml.

Then you need a basic controller to handle the mapping. Something like this:

```
@Controller
public class WebController{


    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String showMessage(){
        return "index";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/showMessage")
    public String showMessage(){
        return "showMessage";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just started learning the Spring framework and I was misunderstanding a bit about the Spring MVC.

Comment: This controller does not compile.  Same error after adding this controller

Comment: Not sure where the variables are being set - ${message}  .  This is simple template and it would not have been difficult  for the STS team to make it work with a simple controller.